# How to access the error log

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Is there any other ways to access the error log in MySQL on ubuntu other than using SSH? I really need to access the error log, but I do not have any privileged to connect via SSH. Please help me.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried asking the Sys Admin of that server for help?

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of ways to view those error logs. All those ways require some kind of configuration by a person with access to shells (that is, ssh access) on the Ubuntu host.

Your best bet is to ask the person who controls that host for help.

Unless things are horribly goofed up (that's a technical term -:) in your MySql server, you can get enough, or almost  enough, troubleshooting information from the errors MySql gives your applications.

Comment: Oh, I thought the technical word was "snafu".

Comment: FUBB, baby, FUBB. That's  what happens when tablespace files get corrupted.